# Get number of records

Tags: python, django

I have an abstract model Group, with 2 childs Company and Bond (I simplified my example). These childs are connected with Contacts thanks to my model WorkRelation. I want to write a function, get_number_of_contacts() that returns the amount of users that are connected with a group through the object WorkRelation.

This is extremely hard because I use generic foreign keys. Is it even possible to implement this method in this construction?

This is my simplified **models.py:**

```
class Group(BaseModel):                                                         
      name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)                         
      *** a lot more attributes ***

--->  def get_number_of_contacts(self):                                           
          return 69                                                               

      class Meta:                                                                 
          abstract = True                                                         


  class Company(Group):                                                           
      def __str__(self):                                                          
          return "Company " + self.name                                           

      class Meta:                                                                 
          app_label = 'groups'                                                    


  class Bond(Group):                                                              
      def __str__(self):                                                          
          return "Bond " + self.name                                              

      class Meta:                                                                 
          app_label = 'groups' 

 class WorkRelation(BaseModel):                                                  
      contact = models.OneToOneField(Contact, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=Tru)
      group_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)         
      group_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()                                    
      group = GenericForeignKey('group_type', 'group_id') 
      *** A lot more attributes ***
```

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understood your question, but you are trying to get the number of total people in the Group, which for me sounds like you can do `Group.objects.get(Group.user).count()`  or even `Group.objects.all().count()`?

Comment: Yes I am trying to get the number of people that are connected with  a Group. But the problem is that Contacts are connected through an object WorkRelation.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you want to count is actually the number of WorkRelation objects for a specific group, which is easy:

```
WorkRelation.objects.filter(group=my_group).count()
```

Since you have a one-to-one relation with Contact you could also count contacts, but that will give you exactly the same result at the cost of an extra database join:

```
Contact.objects.filter(workrelation__group=my_group).count()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I think that this doesn't work because group is an abstract object. It returns the following: django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Field 'group' does not generate an automatic reverse relation and therefore cannot be used for reverse querying. If it is a GenericForeignKey, consider adding a GenericRelation.

Comment: So, add a GenericRelation - see [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#reverse-generic-relations). You can probably add it on the base class, but if not you'll just need to add it on the subclasses, using a different `related_query_name` for each.